# Push icons away when expandig searchview in android toolbar

Tags: android, layout, android-toolbar, android-menu

I'm facing this particular behaviour and I don't know how to fix it..

In my activity I have this toolbar:

[image]

And when you click on the search icon it expands and pushes the other icon to out of the view.

[image]

I want to know how could I keep the icon on the right and reduce the search view space.

This is my menu layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/buscar"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/alimentos_basket"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/alimentos_anadidos"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

In my activity layout I don't have anything

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.irixgalicia.irixhealth.app.comidaDiaria.AnadirAlimentoActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_anadir_alimento" />
```

And these is the code of the activity where I inflate

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_anadir_alimento, menu);
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    final MenuItem contadorItem = menu.findItem(R.id.alimentos_basket);
    contadorItem.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(contadorAlimentos, R.drawable.ic_food_variant_white_36dp));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In my layout I only have the toolbar, not the icons inside.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Has anyone knows how to achieve what I'm looking for..

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ifRoom|collapseActionView` for the attribute `showAsAction`

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```

Comment: Works great for me. Thank you !

Comment: How would I remove the icon on the right instead? I tried using `ifRoom`, thinking it would get put into an overflow menu when the SearchView expanded, but it still gets pushed off the screen

Comment: No! I don't want to use `collapseActionView` because it displays search text instead of search icon and when you fully expand (click on it) there is no way to close (there is X icon button)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `showAsAction` attribute to `ifRoom` and try -

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/alimentos_basket"
  android:orderInCategory="1"
  android:title="@string/alimentos_anadidos"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me; looks like maybe it's a bug in the widget: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36976484

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing the "action_search" from the menu resource file and instead use a MaterialToolbar that wraps a SearchView in your activity xml layout.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/your_menu">
        
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
            app:queryBackground="@color/transparent"
            app:queryHint="@string/search..." />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
```

In your activity you can then use setSupportActionBar() and pass the toolbar