# How to fix the icon in the Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

I need to display SearchView and the add button in the Toolbar, the icon is displayed, but when the SearchView opens, the button is pushed to the edge of the screen as shown below, how can I solve this problem? Is there a way to fix the icon so that it does not move?

[image]

Found a similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976163/push-icons-away-when-expandig-searchview-in-android-toolbar), but it didn't work for me

Below are the elements of the file `main.xml`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add_people"
    android:title="Edit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_person"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"/>
```

Comment: also set "ifRoom" to add button.

Comment: @SagarChavada no, it is necessary that the button is always visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android:orderInCategory attribute to both items.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add_people"
    android:title="Edit"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_person"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"/>
```